# project ideas for a final year CS undergrad/CS masters student

Tags: python

I am enrolled in an online undergrad CS program in Canada and also Georgia Tech OMSCS where I finished computational photography and AI for Robotics.  I also have some deep learning programming knowledge.
For my capstone project in the undergrad, I was building a nutrition app but I lost interest after finding so many other apps and repos with similar ideas.  So I though since I'm taking an intro bioinformatics course this final term before I graduate, I could do a bioinformatics programming project.
Does anyone have any good ideas?  I'm free labor if I can get approval from my course supervisor for your proposal.  Time length would be approximately 10 weeks.
My languages in order of familiarity: Python, C++, C#, Java, C, Javascript, HTML, CSS.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic and unrelated to bioinformatics. In general you should talk to experienced supervisors to guide you for project ideas that can be finished it time while neither over- nor underdemanding you.